# Excel Text to column autoupdate

Tags: excel

I am importing a semicolon separated file into excel using web query and parsing this using the text to column feature in excel. However, this is an one time parsing and the values in the tabs aren't changing to reflect the changes in the original column (ie every time I do a refresh all, I want the delimiter separated columns to reflect the changes).

How do I automatically run the text to columns features every time there is a change in the original content?

Comment: is the source indeed a query or already directly a text file?

Comment: Its a text file already. It has semicolon separated values.

Comment: Do you want to run the Text to Columns in a macro every time the source file is updated or do you want to use (many) formula's in all the cells?

Comment: I want Text to columns to run everytime the source file is updated

Answer (score 0):

As it is a text file already you could also use the Data > From Text option, that will automatically apply the text-to-columns functionality to it.

Now you can have it actively linked as Connection in your workbook and whenever it is updated text-to-column will be applied.